# Date format form Jan 30 to 2011-01-30

Tags: php, datetime, date, format

I have the following date format in a xml sheet:
Jan 30
and I want to display as:
2011-01-30

2011 being the current year

Can someone help me with that?

Comment: Closevoting as too localized because I don't think this place needs yet another "How to reformat date X as date Y". The OP should be able to find the answer and/or any required hints in http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=format+date+php

Answer (score 3):

[strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) will use the current year if none is specified, so this would work

```
$t=strtotime("Jan 30");

echo strftime("%Y-%m-%d", $t);
```

Answer (score 1):

`strtotime` + `date` gives you:

```
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime('30 Jan')); //echoes '2011-01-30'
```

Answer (score 0):

care to post the xml?

in anycase, take the string
`$x = "Jan 30"`

add 2011

`$x = $x . ' ' . date('Y');`

convert it to date time and format it

```
$y = date_format('Y-m-d', strtotime($x));

echo $y;`
```

strtotime is your key here, it converts most any date format into seconds since the epoch, then all you need do is use the date_format function

ps... if you like my answer, accept it as the answer to bring your accepted question ratio, otherwise people will be less likely to answer your questions